# captcha encoding not recieved for aadhar api call using mashape api

Tags: ruby

I am using an 3rd party api in mashape to access the aadhar api and using the unirest http library to send a get request
Link for the mashape api https://www.mashape.com/blaazetech/aadhar-card-status

```
response = Unirest.get "https://aadharcardstatus.p.mashape.com/getToken.php",
headers:{
"X-Mashape-Key" => "LIZjil6nXlmshZxGZzLEZndcqiIHp1Ka0Zqjsn5rHE3u4g90TZ"
 }
```

and this is the response I am getting when I run the above ruby program

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Connection: keep-alive
 Content-Length: 53
 Content-Type: application/json
 Date: Sun, 11 Jan 2015 13:09:03 GMT
 Server: Mashape/5.0.5
 Via: 1.1 vegur
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.27

{
  "secretKey": "jTbwAIPfVLI=",
  "captchaImageEncoded": ""
 }
```

The captcha value is not being returned in the http response I am getting. Any idea on why the captcha value is not being sent back?

Answer (score 0):

you should consult the API provider's documentation or contact them directly for support